# lvm volume's file system suddenly changed from ext4 to silicon_medley_raid_member

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, mount, lvm

Today my laptop suddenly showed me this text at booting:

```
mount: mounting /dev/dm-0 on /root failed: No such device
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
...
```

i booted from livecd and checked all filesystems (there are three lvm volumes `local-root`, `local-home` and `local-swap` also there is /boot partition at /dev/sda1 that is not in lvm) with `fsck`

Same result after restarting..

Then while mounting my volumes for `chroot`ing to them i saw that `local-root` can't be mounted with this reason:

```
# mount /dev/mapper/local-root /mnt
mount: unknown filesystem type 'silicon_medley_raid_member'
```

Darn! WHY?! why ME and NOW?!!

i've checked this twice:

```
# blkid /dev/mapper/local-root
/dev/mapper/local-root: TYPE="silicon_medley_raid_member"
```

However, i still can easily mount it with manually defined fstype:

```
# mount -t ext4 /dev/mapper/local-root /mnt
```

But i don't know what to do next, how to change FSTYPE back to ext4 without loosing data? (yeah, i have a backup, but only for 'local-home' volume, and i don't want to reinstall full system rght now..)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a lot of fun with the same bug today and can't count all the filesystem checks, boot-repairs, grub-reinstalls, ...

It turns out the solution is quite easy. Just extend your root volgroup by a few bytes and the type will be fixed to ext4 automatically.

```
lvextend -L +512B /dev/mapper/local-root
```

I found the solution here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1011007

Comment: Thanks Nils! Unfortunately can't check this solution coz i've already reinstalled system, but i'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. However, my LVM volume group was full so I couldn't try the hack mentioned in the other solution.

Instead I used `wipefs` to see that my partition actually had 2 signatures. One was correct (ext4). The other was incorrect (silicon_medley_raid_member).

---

First I booted with a LiveUSB that matched my version of Ubuntu (14.04). Then I ran this to see the two signatures:

```
sudo wipefs -n /dev/mapper/local-root
```

The output looked something like this:

```
offset               type
----------------------------------------------------------------
0x4444               ext4   [filesystem]
                     LABEL: root
                     UUID:  <redacted>

0xfffffff            silicon_medley_raid_member (raid)
```

(Offsets changed to protect the innocent.)

Then I ran this to test removing the bad signature.

```
sudo wipefs -n -o 0xfffffff /dev/mapper/local-root
```

Where `0xfffffff` is the offset listed from the first command.

Finally I ran it again without `-n` to actually write the change to disk.

```
sudo wipefs -o <offset> /dev/mapper/local-root
```

And now `blkid /dev/mapper/local-root` showed the `TYPE` as `ext4`.

---

Be **very careful** when using `wipefs`. You should have a backup before doing it. And certainly don't use this method if you don't actually see two signatures.